# AnyLogic, resource choice with particular agent conditions

Tags: java, resources, anylogic

I'm using Anylogic. I have an agent Customer and five Technicians (they are resources). In agent statechart, I have to insert a list of 12 failures that can randomly occurr to customer. Each of these failures require a different combination skills (in my model exist four skills) . Each of five technicians  has different combinations of skills.

[Combination cases are in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5zjB.png)

I model failures with an agent variable "Issue", and an option list (with class "Issue") with 12 number. It could be correct?
In Main, in seize block, how can specify which technical resource to use for each agent?? I know that I have to use customize resource choice, but I need help to insert code.
An another question is whether to insert population of 5 technicians in the agent-based part, or to create 5 different agents who call themselves "Technician 1", "Technician 2" and so on...
Sorry for the numerous questions
Thank you so much!

Comment: can you show the contents of the *Issue* entity that is going to be asking for technicians and which property of *Technician* it need to match?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My Issue entity is defined by an Option List with class "Issue", it has twelve values ("a" , "b" , "c" and so on...). I want to assign one of these randomly for each customer enters in process. Then in "seize technician" I have 5 resource pools (each with one technician) of type Technician. For example I want to say that if occurs Issue "a", the only good technicians are  number 1 or 3 or 4; if occurs "b", the only good technicians are number 2 or 4.... and etc.  How can I specify this in "customize resource choice? I would connect type of Issue with suitable technician

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts:

1. Randomly assigning one of *Issue* values to a property of your Customer agent - this can be done by create a parameter of type *Issue* in Customer agent (let's call it `p_issue`) and setting its default value to `randomFrom(Issue.class)`. This way, every time a Customer class is create its `p_issue` parameter will be set to a random selection from range of *Issue* values.
2. Matching a Customer with a technician resource - if you have 5 separate pools instead of 1 pool with 5 technicians then the simplest thing to do is to use a [SelectOutput5](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/selectoutput5.html) block. and have 5 seizes pointing at a pool each. In condition field you can put something like:

```java
    agent.p_issue == Issue.a || agent.p_issue == Issue.b
```

The above case would work for matching an Customer agent with `p_issue` equal to `a` or `b` to a particular **Seize** that points to a single resource pool.

---

Update: you parameter should look like the image.

[image]

Note: this will pick issues at random, so there is no guarantee that each value is unique, i.e. if you have 10 issue values and generate a 100 customers then approx 10% of them will have `p_issue=Issue.a`, 10%, `p_issue=Issue.b`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All clear. But how can I be sure that each agent entering in the model has a Issue value (I hope different values) ? Where can I specify "randomFrom(Issue.class)" in Main descrete model? I don't understand if the parameter value can change atuomatically for each customer or I have to specify it. Thanks again and sorry.

Comment: I've clarified the answer